# How to request for a non-json octet-stream in angular 6 using HttpClient?

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 6 project. One of the web service return the `octet-stream` of a file. I have to create a `Blob` of the file and download it. I am not getting the response inside `subscribe`. How can I request for non-json `octet-stream` response?

```
downloadFile(filePath: string): Observable<HttpResponse<Any>> {
    this.http.post<any>(this.getFileDownloadPath(), { stringParam: filePath }, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(
        (resp) => {
            this.triggerDownloadFile(resp.body);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log('err');
        }
    );
}

triggerDownloadFile(data: Response) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: Add `responseType: 'blob'` to your post options

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  fileUrl;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const data = 'some text';
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

    this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }

}
```

```html
<a [href]="fileUrl" download="file.txt">DownloadFile</a>
```